# cv::dnn::Net forward function is very slow for YOLO object detection

Tags: c++, opencv, yolo

this->net.forward(outs, getOutputsNames(this->net));
The forward function of cv::dnn::net is very slow. Is there any way to optimize it? I am using it for object detection through YOLO v3. It takes around 2 seconds per image.

```
void ObjectDetector::runInference(cv::Mat& frame, std::string item, std::string output_path, std::string imagename)
{

    cv::Mat blob;
    cv::dnn::blobFromImage(frame, blob, 1/255.0, cv::Size(416, 416), cv::Scalar(0,0,0), true, false);
    
    //Sets the input to the network
    this->net.setInput(blob);
        
    // Runs the forward pass to get output of the output layers
    std::vector<cv::Mat> outs;
    
       clock_t start, end;
  
    /* Recording the starting clock tick.*/
    start = clock();

    /* below code is very slow */
    this->net.forward(outs, getOutputsNames(this->net));
    /* above code is very slow */

    end = clock();
    double time_taken = double(end - start) / double(CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
    std::cout << "Time taken for getOutputnames is : " << std::fixed 
         << time_taken << std::setprecision(5);
    std::cout << " sec " << std::endl;
   
    postprocess(frame, outs, item, output_path, imagename);
}
```

Comment: What kind of cpu ware you using? YOLO is expensive, it has a lot of operations. However, on a recent intel i7 cpu you should observe forward passes of about 500 ms if I remember it right.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are running your code via on CPU backend. Since you are running a huge weight files, its normal to get lower fps in today's CPUs. Actually there are 2 ways you can increase your speed:

1. This solution comes with a **trade-off**. You get speed but lose
   accuracy. This solution is decreasing width of network's input
   image. Your current values are **(416,416)** you may decrease these
   2 values and you will speed up your fps. However, your accuracy will
   get down.
2. The cleanest solution is using GPU. If you have a gpu
   hardware(**CUDA capable**), then you can change the network backend
   to GPU and you will get speed with the same accuracy.